# IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved

Tags: python

> IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
> result5, _ = quad(H_T_s, M_mu_nominal ** 2, (mD0_sampled - mK_sampled) ** 2,
> HTs.py:60: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
> If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze
> the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a
> local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will
> probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator
> on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
> result5, _ = quad(H_T_s, M_mu_nominal ** 2, (mD0_sampled - mK_sampled) ** 2,
> HTs.py:60: IntegrationWarning: The algorithm does not converge.  Roundoff error is detected
> in the extrapolation table.  It is assumed that the requested tolerance
> cannot be achieved, and that the returned result (if full_output = 1) is
> the best which can be obtained.
> result5, _ = quad(H_T_s, M_mu_nominal ** 2, (mD0_sampled - mK_sampled) ** 2,
> HTs form factor value of D0_to_Kminus: -0.6206823068507045 +/- 24.997285674551392

```
def H_T_s(q2, mD0, mK, f_T, cT, pT):
    return (-(lambda_K(q2, mD0, mK)) ** 0.5 / (mD0 + mK)) * fT(q2, z(q2, tplus(mD0, mK), t0(mD0, mK)), z0(q2, tplus(mD0, mK), t0(mD0, mK)), f_T, cT, pT)


# Number of samples for Monte Carlo integration
num_samples = 1000

# Performing Monte Carlo integration
HTs = []

for _ in range(num_samples):
    # Sample from the uncertainty distributions of the parameters
    
    mD0_sampled = np.random.normal(mD0_nominal, mD0_std_dev)
    mK_sampled = np.random.normal(mK_nominal, mK_std_dev)
    f_T_sampled = np.random.normal(f_T_nominal, f_T_std_dev)
    cT_sampled = np.random.normal(cT_nominal, cT_std_dev)
    pT_sampled = np.random.normal(pT_nominal, pT_std_dev)

    #print("mD0:", mD0_sampled)
    #print("mK:", mK_sampled)
    result5, _ = quad(H_T_s, M_mu_nominal ** 2, (mD0_sampled - mK_sampled) ** 2,
                     args=(mD0_sampled, mK_sampled, f_T_sampled, cT_sampled, pT_sampled), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08, limit = 50)
    #print(result5)
    HTs.append(result5)
```

This is my code part where I am getting Integration warning, I am wondering for a help how do I debug this.
It will be very helpful if someone suggest me the solution. If more information is required I will provide.
Thank you

Comment: The warning provides several possible solutions (changing limit, splitting interval, using special purpose integrator, etc...) Do those solutions help? If not, what issues are you running into?